# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception Flutter

Tags: flutter, api

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> D:\Development\ULTIMAT POS\App POS Backup\UltimatePOS_Flutter_1.7.1\Ultimate_POS_Flutter\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:34: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/launcher_icon (aka com.pnn.pos:mipmap/launcher_icon) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1..........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android build failed due to mipmap/launcher_icon missing or path change. without launcher_icon app not install .
drag and drop app icon to mipmap & re-run ur app.